# Explicitly choosing implementation methods for interfaces in Go

Tags: go, methods, struct, interface, embedding

Say I have to following interfaces `Foo` and `A` and `B` which implements `Foo`:

```golang
type Foo interface {
    SayHi()
    SayBye()
}

type A struct {}

func(a A) SayHi() {}

func(a A) SayBye() {}

type B struct {}

func(b B) SayHi() {}

func(b B) SayBye() {}
```

What would be the best *syntactic approach* if I want the `SayHi` method from `A` but the `SayBye` method from `B`?

I could always do:

```golang
type AB struct {
    a A
    b B
}

func(ab AB) SayHi() { ab.a.SayHi() }

func(ab AB) SayBye() { ab.a.SayBye() }
```

But that requires me to create a wrapper for every method. Another approach would be to embed `A` and `B` into `AB` but that would create a conflict.

Comment: You can do that by struct embedding, something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/74RphthhN36
But I honestly can't imagine a scenario where that would be necessary

Comment: Your solution @Kosanovic does not implement the interface `Foo` which maybe required. But it is simpler to read. If you publish it as an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed 2 *interface* types which only define the parts (methods) you want to use ("inherit") from the different types:

```
type AB struct {
    Hier
    Byer
}

type Hier interface {
    SayHi()
}
type Byer interface {
    SayBye()
}
```

Basically using `Hier` and `Byer` "masks" other methods, so embedding them (instead of `A` and `B`) will resolve the name conflict (the ambiguity).

Let's make implementations print who they are for verification:

```
func (a A) SayHi()  { fmt.Println("A says Hi") }
func (a A) SayBye() { fmt.Println("A says Bye") }
func (b B) SayHi()  { fmt.Println("B says Hi") }
func (b B) SayBye() { fmt.Println("B says Bye") }
```

Using it:

```
var ab Foo = AB{
    Hier: A{},
    Byer: B{},
}
ab.SayHi()
ab.SayBye()
```

And output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-umo6Xg-LDJ)):

```
A says Hi
B says Bye
```

Of course if we now have `Hier` and `Byer`, we can use them to simplify `Foo` if we want to:

```
type Foo interface {
    Hier
    Byer
}
```

Comment: This requires manually defining 2 separate interfaces that contain methods that have already been defined (`SayHi` and `SayBye` are already part of `Foo`), but because I don't see a better way to do this I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: @thestateofmay Yes, this requires "some" extra work, but you don't have to add method implementations like in your question, just the method declarations. And if you think about it: you have to tell somehow which methods you want from `A` and `B`, and designating a method is the work of declaring it. Also note that if you reuse `Hier` and `Byer` when declaring `Foo` (like suggested at the end of the answer), then you actually just declare each method once.